# Sum similar to the binomial sum

Tags: summation, combinations, binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem

The basic binomial theorem is 
$$(x+y)^n=\sum_{k=0}^n \binom nk x^ky^{n-k}\ .$$
I want to evalueate the sum similar to this.. 
$$\sum_{k=0}^n \binom nk x^k(1-x)^{n-k}\binom nky^k(c-y)^{n-k}\ .$$
Can this expression be further simplified ?
Here, $c$ is just a scalar s.t. $c\in[0,1].$

Comment: @Servaes That's just some scalar.. which doesn't have to be 1.

Comment: @Servaes, Fixed. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: A pretty unhelpful way to simplify this is by writing it as a hypergeometric function

Comment: This is $\sum_{k=0}^n\binom nk^2 u^{n-k}v^k$ for suitable $u$ and $v$. As far as I know, there is no way this can be "simplified".

Comment: Perhaps if you edit your question to explain what problem left you wanting this evaluated, we can solve that problem another say. We might even find the above expression isn't the right one for your purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Using $$\sum_{k=0}^{n} {n \choose k}^2 A ^k B^{n-k} = B^{n} ~_2F_1[-n,-n;1;\frac{A}{B}]$$ So in terms og Gauss hypergeometric funcyion $~_2F_1$, you get

$$S=\sum_{k=0}^{n} {n \choose k} x^k (1-x)^{n-l} {n \choose k} y^k (c-y)^{n-k}$$
$$\implies S=\sum_{k=0}^{n} {n \choose k}^2 (x)^k [(1-x)(c-y)]^{n-k}.$$
$$\implies S=[(1-x)(c-y)]^n
~ ~_2F_1 \left[-n,-n;1;\frac{xy}{(1-x)(c-y)}\right].$$